# System center - Monitoring REST web services

Tags: web-services, system-center, system-monitoring

As the title suggests, is anyone aware of a way to monitor RESTful web services using System Center? With System Center being a Microsoft product, it is more geared toward WCF, particularly XML-based, inputs etc.

Answer (score -1):

I looked into this a while back and saw some mentions of people using URLGenie MP to accomplish this (though predominantly SOAP-based APIs).

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tysonpaul/2015/05/04/urlgenie-management-pack-for-scom-an-easy-powerful-solution-for-bulk-website-monitoring/

There was a discussion here about using the Web Application Monitoring template in the Authoring pane to create this. Or using the Universal Connector from the 2007 R2 Connectors:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/systemcenter/en-US/470094b0-1ee4-4d4e-9c65-0dd99d95a73f/scom-integration-with-restful-based-web-services?forum=operationsmanagergeneral